# Have a problem with saving figures in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, fft

I have a problem with saving figures. This code does FFT for signal and after that should save FFT in .png in separate files. The first figure is ok but the next ones have in a figure all previous FFT, maybe that is a typical problem, do you know how to fix it?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

txt_files = glob.glob("*.pom") #format of files
print(txt_files)


for i in range(len(txt_files)):

    
    mat = np.genfromtxt(txt_files[i])
    #x = np.delete(mat, [0, 6] , axis=0)
    a = np.delete(mat, 0, axis=1)
    b = mat[1, 0] - mat[0, 0]

    std = a.std()
    mean = a.mean()

    print(std, mean)

    Fs = 5000  # sumpling freq IF TIME IN FIRST COLUMN
    tstep = 1 / Fs  # sumple time interval

    N = np.size(a)  # number of samples

    t = np.linspace(0, (N - 1) * tstep, N)  # time step
    fstep = Fs / N
    f = np.linspace(0, (N - 1) * fstep, N)  # freq step

    X = np.fft.fft2(a)
    X_mag = np.abs(X) / N

    f_plot = f[0:int(N / 2 + 1)]

    X_mag_plot = 2 * X_mag[0:int(N / 2 + 1)]
    X_mag_plot[0] = X_mag_plot[0] / 2

    plt.plot(f_plot, X_mag_plot, "-k", linewidth=0.5)
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.xscale("log")
    plt.axis([1, 1000, 0, 0.01])
    plt.grid(True)
    #plt.text(45, .025, r'$\mu=100,\ \sigma=15$', backgroundcolor="w")
    plt.text(300, 0.01, f'std={std:.3f} \nmean={mean:.3f}', backgroundcolor="w")

    #plt.show()

    np.savetxt(txt_files[i] + "_Widmo.txt", X_mag_plot, delimiter="\t")
    plt.savefig(txt_files[i] + ".png", dpi=250)
    if i == 1:
        np.savetxt(txt_files[0] + "_Fs.txt", f_plot, delimiter="\t")
    del f_plot
    del X_mag_plot
    del txt_files[i]
```

Comment: Hi, I guess, you need to clear the image after saving and become ready for the next loop. To do this you can place `plt.clf()` right after `plt.savefig`. Do let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you continue working in the same figure. Try and do one of the following:

Open a new figure in each iteration of your loop. This is not optimal as you will potentially open up a lot of figures:

```
plt.figure()
```

The other option, which is more optimal, is to close the figure in each iteration after saving it:

```
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you

Comment: @VasylSokolenko If this answer solved your problem, you should consider the opportunity to approve it, clicking the check mark on the left of the answer.